# Combined trigger in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite, triggers

I have these tables:

- Movie ( mID, title, year, director )
- Reviewer ( rID, name )
- Rating ( rID, mID, stars, ratingDate )

and some views:

- View `LateRating` contains movie ratings after January 20, 2011. The view contains the movie ID, movie title, number of stars, and rating date.

  ```
  create view LateRating as 
    select distinct R.mID, title, stars, ratingDate 
    from Rating R, Movie M 
    where R.mID = M.mID 
    and ratingDate > '2011-01-20'
  ```
- View `HighlyRated` contains movies with at least one rating above 3 stars. The view contains the movie ID and movie title.

  ```
  create view HighlyRated as 
    select mID, title 
    from Movie 
    where mID in (select mID from Rating where stars > 3)
  ```
- View `NoRating` contains movies with no ratings in the database. The view contains the movie ID and movie title.

  ```
  create view NoRating as 
    select mID, title 
    from Movie 
    where mID not in (select mID from Rating)
  ```

Here's my data set : https://prod-c2g.s3.amazonaws.com/db/Winter2013/files/viewmovie.sql

I should write a single instead-of trigger that combines triggers to enable simultaneous updates to attributes mID, title, and/or stars in view LateRating.

I can write simple triggers but this looks complex?How can I approach this problem?

Comment: what if you'll combine those into one view?

Comment: @BeHappy Well that would be cheating :)

Comment: Try to understand this 3 points (before you try to resolve your questions):
1º You should create a primary keys for each of your tables. In your case, Movie(mID) Reviewer(rID) Rating(rID,mID) would be nice. 
2º You should not update your primary keys. 
3º Views are virtual tables, you do not update them.

Comment: You can't have triggers that update views since a view doesn't actually store any data, it is merely a representation of data on other tables.  Are you trying to update records in the 'Rating' table if they show up in the 'LateRating' view?

Comment: What have you tried? You could at least attempt a solution before asking us to do your homework.

Comment: Please follow Stanford's online classes honor code